# Chat client with a web interface

Tags: web, irc, chat

I'm trying to set up a chat client on my Ubuntu server that I'll be able to access via a browser with my other local computers. Specifically, it would need to support XMPP and IRC.

My first thoughts were Pidgin and Empathy, but they don't seem to have web interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### IRC clients

Take a look at this wikipedia page: [Comparison of Internet Relay Chat clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_clients). There are such tools like, [mibbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mibbit). There are others on the list.

#### Browser based

Additionally you could use something like [ChatZilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatZilla) which is built into Firefox.

#### XMPP clients

The xmpp.org website maintains a [list of clients](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/) which includes whether they're web based or standalone.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I don't think either of those support XMPP/Jabber.

Comment: It's been listed as a *todo* on their blog since 2010: http://blog.mibbit.com/?p=791.

Comment: Added a link to a list of XMPP, not sure if they're irc capable or not. I've used jwchat which is only XMPP. Never tried any of the others.